# Process other application activity in long loop

Tags: vba, loops

I have a long running loop in an unfortunately large excel file that I'm scripting over. I seem to remember a keyword you could put in a loop statement that would cause the program to sort of temporarily "pause" the loop and process other application input, like...mouse movement, screen redraws and such.

This might be a leftover memory from the bad old days of vb5..does anybody have any idea what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean

```
DoEvents
```

You find further information in Microsoft's Support database:

> **[Definition of DoEvents in Visual Basic for Applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118468)**

Comment: AHH Thank you! Ohh man that was killing me...I knew it was something stupid simple. I just couldn't figure out what to search for.